# "Selection.objects" doesn't seem to work in open prefab hierarchy window

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to select several game objects in open prefab but `Selection.objects`, which normally works for scene game objects, like on this picture:

[image]

doesn't seem to work properly for prefab objects.

Actually, the **Inspector** window *displays common properties of the selected objects as expected* but in the **Hierarchy** window *they are not selected (highlighted)* like on the picture above.

Here is how my script looks like in my `MyEditor : EditorWindow`:

```
int childObjectsCount;
string prefabName;
...

if (AssetDatabase.LoadMainAssetAtPath(prefabName) is GameObject prefab)
{
    if (AssetDatabase.OpenAsset(prefab))
    {
        if (childObjectsCount > 0)
        {
            List<GameObject> innerObjects = FindInnerObjects(prefab);
            Selection.objects = innerObjects.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `FindInnerObjects`? and what do you mean by not selected/highlighted in the Hiearchy window ... Prefabs as all assets live only in the Assets folder -> Projects view ...

Comment: @derHugo They are not highlighted the way they are normally highlighted (visually 
 in *Hierarchy*)  when using `Selection.objects` for the scene objects. `FindInnerObjects` just returns all children game objects of the prefab.

Comment: Maybe could GetComponentsInChildren<T> work for you ?

Comment: @JesúsNarváezTamés probably not on prefabs

Comment: @Sergey could you add screenshots of what it looks like vs what you would like to happen?

Comment: Also did you try to rather use `gameObjects -> Returns the actual game object selection. Includes Prefabs, non-modifiable objects.` while only using `object -> The actual unfiltered selection from the Scene.` but prefabs are not from the scene ...

Comment: @derHugo edited.
I couldn't understand what you meant in your second comment.

Comment: @Sergey you are talking about prefabs and the hierachy .. which one do you mean? In the Hierachy view you see instances of a prefab. But the prefab itself is an asset that only lives in the Projects view (Assets folder).

Comment: @derHugo you can open any prefab asset (double-click on the prefab in the *Project* or in the *Hierachy* scene objects tree)  and it will be shown in the *Hierachy* with its full structure (inner game objects or other prefabs). The `AssetDatabase.OpenAsset(prefab)` method does the same.

Comment: @Sergey that's true but I'm pretty sure in that moment Unity creates a temporary instance of the prefab, make changes and writes them back to the asset. But now at least I know what you are talking about ;)

Comment: @derHugo that's likely true, but I don't think in this case `Selection.objects` should work differently. Actually, it's half working: Inspector displays the properties of the selected objects, but the objects themselves are not highlighted in the Hierarchy so it's hard to guess what objects are selected in the prefab. And the objects tree is not being unfolded.

Comment: @Sergey my guess would be that `prefab` still refers to the asset, not the current instance displayed in the Hierachy View. That would explain why you might get current values (Inspector) but no selection as the asset doesn't fold out

Comment: @derHugo thank you for your comments! I was just hoping there was a way to fix it somehow for my script that looks for game objects and prefabs with missing scripts and shows them in the hierarchy. But it would live without proper highlighting as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is that the `Gameobject` specified by *`Selection.objects` is not the `Gameobject` in the current PrefabStage*, so we need to get the current `PrefabStage`

```
// LoadPrefab
GameObject assetGameObject = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<GameObject>(prefabPath);
// OpenPrefab
AssetDatabase.OpenAsset(assetGameObject);
// GetPrefabStage
PrefabStage prefabStage = PrefabStageUtility.GetCurrentPrefabStage();
// Get Root Gameobejct Of Prefab Which We Are Editing
GameObject instanceGameobject = prefabStage.prefabContentsRoot;
// Then Select It , it works well(highlight)
Selection.objects = new Object[] {instanceGameobject };
```